# How to convert the elements of an array into a number ? Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a NumPy array: `x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`.  How do I convert this array into the integer `12345`?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [8]: import numpy as np

In [9]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [10]: int("".join(map(str, a)))
Out[10]: 12345
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `sum()` function with a generator:

```
>>> sum(e * 10 ** i for i, e in enumerate(x[::-1]))
12345
```

or, alternatively:

```
>>> sum(e * 10 ** (len(x) - i-1) for i, e in enumerate(x))
12345
```

or you could use `str.join`, again with a generator:

```
>>> int(''.join(str(i) for i in x))
12345
```

---

**why?**

In the first example, we use a generator to yield each number multiplied by `10` to the power of its position in the array, we then add these together to get our final result. This may be easier to see if we use a `list-comprehension`, rather than a `generator` to see what is going on:

```
>>> [e * 10 ** i for i, e in enumerate(x[::-1])]
[5, 40, 300, 2000, 10000]
```

and then it is clear from here that, through summing these numbers together, we will get the result of `12345`. Note, however, that we had to reverse `x` before using this, as otherwise the numbers would be multiplied by the wrong powers of `10` (i.e. the first number would be multiplied by `1` rather than `10000`).

In the second snippet, the code simply uses a different method to get the right power of `10` for each index. Rather than reversing the array, we simply subtract the index from the length of `x` (`len(x)`), and minus one more so that the first element is `10000`, not `100000`. This is simply an alternative.

Finally, the last method should be fairly self-explanatory. We are merely joining together the stringified versions of each number in the array, and then converting back to an `int` to get our result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way via `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
f = np.fromiter((10**(len(x)-i) for i in range(1, len(x)+1)), dtype=int)

y = np.sum(x*f)  # 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to convert the array into a `numpy.string`, replace the output spaces with no characters and subset all but the beginning and end then finally convert it to `int`

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = int(np.str(x).replace(' ','')[1:-1])
```

## Example Run

```
In [75]: x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [76]: y = int(np.str(x).replace(' ', '')[1:-1])

In [77]: y
Out[77]: 12345

In [78]: type(y)
Out[78]: int
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [24]: x
Out[24]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [25]: np.dot(x, 10**np.arange(len(x)-1, -1, -1))
Out[25]: 12345
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.